# What are the rules governing multiple accounts (i.e. sockpuppets)?

Tags: discussion, faq, accounts, sock-puppets, duplicate-accounts

I noticed some users have a separate account (sock puppet) that operates as a chatbot.

- Are we allowed to have multiple accounts?
- What can we use those accounts for?
- What are the rules governing multiple accounts?

Also see: [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)

---

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: What are the rules governing multiple accounts and downvotes?

Comment: @JL2210 the same user shouldn't up or downvote the same post from multiple accounts

Comment: What if, say, a user writes a super long helpful answer, posts it, forgets their password over a few years, creates a new account, finds their old answer helpful, and upvotes it without realizing that it's theirs?

Comment: @JL2210 I recommend they get a check for their memory ;)

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't think it's unreasonable to not recognize one's own answer from a few years back, if we remove the "super long" bit, which isn't even relevant for JL's argument... and forgetting I've upvoted a random post a couple of years back is even more likely.

Comment: @JohnDvorak we can beg to differ. Recognising one's own work is an important thing in life. Professionally, academically, legally and socially. More importantly, saying you didn't realise it was your own work is not going to wash as an excuse.

Comment: Suggested followup question: What are the rules governing coordinated voting?

Comment: @JohnDvorak If it's "super long", you'd have to scroll down a little bit to see the profile. If it's short, you should pretty much see it right away.

Comment: @JL2210 That's happened to me before, but with comments. I see a comment and think "Wow! I totally agree with that person! They've expressed my views perfectly!" and upvote, then realize a short while later that it was a long-forgotten comment of mine that I saw...

Comment: @forest At least it was a comment. That way you don't get any benefit from it.

Comment: I'd doubt any flags would be raised for an _occasional_ one off anyway. I'd imagine/hope that it would have to be a consistent pattern of upvoting your own answers before any action is taken.

Comment: @Lewis - I would assume there is a path of escalation as far as penalty. As far as enforcement, at the very least, an own vote would be reversed.

Comment: @forest Better than the comments (or code) you see where you're like "Wow, what a dummy..." and then you realize it was past self who wrote it.

Comment: @JL2210 et al: Assuming the old account you lost the password to is not going to have anyone logging into it again, this seems like a mostly hypothetical issue that doesn't actually matter. If mods actually caught it, which seems unlikely, presumably they'd actually help the affected user work out account recovery/merge rather than just banning then going dark.

Comment: @R.. mods do refer users to the community team for account recovery and merges. You'd be surprised what gets detected.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: OK, so then is the second "if they did" part of my comment accurate then? What I was getting at is that I don't think this makes sense to worry about as a policy violation/punishment issue, and it sounds like you're saying that's right and that it would be treated as an account recovery one.

Comment: @R.. part of the mod message with suspicious voting includes an option for the person to ask to merge multiple accounts. So it's something that is taken into consideration.Sometimes it's obvious an account is created for the purposes of circumventing a post ban or to upvote another account. Sometimes a group of friends or colleagues will actively upvote each other. Depending on the severity and pattern of the case people can be given the benefit of the doubt for making a mistake. If they repeat the offence, not so much :|

Comment: @YvetteColomb: To be honest I've come across my own questions and answers several times without realizing they're mine until I saw the name on them. Say what you want about my memory, but I don't expect I'm the only one this happens to. (But then again, I have >1k answers just on StackOverflow, and maybe you're imagining someone with 5 answers...)

Comment: @Mehrdad it was a joke. As for upvoting your own answers with a second account - don't do it. If you say "but I didn't know they were my answers" and you continue to do it, you'll be suspended.

Comment: Is this really a thing, in the big picture? Does it _really_ affect SE/SO? Imho, we might get a “freak” question/answer here and there, but the general trend should not be affected. It is hard to believe for me that one sets up so many sock puppets to really make a difference.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg it's more a problem with deceitful voting practices. It happens more than you'd think. In terms of all this "accidental voting" stuff, it's almost non-existent, hence my reaction to having to continue discussing it.

Comment: There is a big fat block with your old user name and avatar at the bottom of every question you have authored -- there is no excuse for not knowing a question is yours. If you sock-puppet between accounts in any way, both should be closed and you should be banned.

Comment: agree totally with David.  This was the first thing i thought.  It's entirely possible to not recognize your code but i find it hard to believe you would forget a user name unless maybe it was a string of random numbers.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

This is what Jeff Atwood had to say when the question came up a few years ago:

> It is not a problem to have multiple accounts, as long as they aren't voting for each other and doing other sockpuppet-y things.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35607)

While this is nice and clear it doesn't go into much (if any!) detail about what's not allowed. So I'll expand on the two main points.

"Voting" includes:

- voting on posts from your main account with your alternate account(s) and vice versa.
- accepting the other account's answer on your post.
- awarding a bounty to the other account
- posting bounties on questions belonging to the other account
- voting on posts or comments from other (3rd party) accounts with your main account and your alternate account(s).
- flagging other posts or comments with all the accounts you control. This is especially bad when it's spam or rude & abusive flags.
- casting close votes on the same question with multiple accounts.

"Other sockpuppet-y things" include:

- using multiple accounts to circumvent system-imposed restrictions.
- using alternative accounts to circumvent suspension by a moderator.
- posting answers with the alternate account to your questions (see the point about voting above).
- suggesting edits to your posts with your alternative account.
- approving suggested edits from one account for the other.

These should not be seen as exhaustive lists, because I'm bound to have missed something.

It boils down to:

- If you do something with one or more alternate accounts that you wouldn't be able to do with just your main account, then that's against the rules.
- While we can't stop you creating multiple accounts, if those accounts interact **in any way**, then that's against the rules, even if your main or alternate account(s) stand to lose reputation or privileges as a result.

### So how can I get my alternative account privileges?

Given the above restrictions, it may seem difficult to get privileges for an alternative account, such as the ability to post in chat (chat bots) or cast automatic flags. But it's not impossible.

If you want an alternative account to have privileges, **it must earn reputation on its own**, rather than through the help of your main account or any other accounts you're in control of. For instance, it can post helpful answers to others' questions, ask great questions, or suggest great edits (that you refrain from reviewing). From [this Shog9 post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288158):

> If you want a sockpuppet to have reputation, then earn it. [That's what I do with my sockpuppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/335934/serious-human), and I certainly have a lot more opportunities to abuse the system than y'all do. If you can't play it straight while creating your bot, what confidence can we have in the bot being honorable once it's up and running?

If you're concerned that people will react to your account differently once they know that it's an alternate account you're trying to earn reputation on, you [can take actions to stop that from happening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288144/how-should-a-bot-earn-enough-reputation-to-perform-the-actions-necessary-for-tha/288158#comment935451_288158) (e.g. telling others not to upvote posts made by your alternative account unless they would otherwise merit upvotes as high-quality, not telling others that you're going to make posts through it, etc.). Provided you don't fall afoul of the guidelines above, this is allowed.

Also see:

- [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)
- [How should a bot earn enough reputation to perform the actions necessary for that bot?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288144/how-should-a-bot-earn-enough-reputation-to-perform-the-actions-necessary-for-tha)

Comment: "if those accounts interact **in any way**, then that's against the rules," Given that "any way" is in bold, this would not allow you to interact with a chatbot you own. (It wouldn't be against this rule to *create* it, but it would to respond to it/give it commands in a chatroom).

Comment: @Adriaan I was thinking about interactions on the main site when I wrote that. It would also apply to chat if the second account *wasn't* a chatbot.

Comment: Note that there is one explicit exception to sockpuppetry — testing a possible security vulnerability. I can't find the page on it, but I I recall seeing it when I went to report one.

Comment: @jhpratt - but in that case you're not really doing something that you can't do with your main account. Some mods maintain a low rep account so they can remind themselves what the site looks like to newcomers. I tend to use browse it logged out for that purpose.

Comment: How about second accounts to avoid quality control measures? I've had a previous discussion with a user that advocated using a second account to ask questions you know will get poor reception (debugging/poor effort ones) to avoid rep loss. My opinion is that shouldn't be allowed, but we don't have official guidance on it.

Comment: @ChrisF I imagine if there was some weird but with regard to voting, close votes, etc. that it would be acceptable as well. Without going into too much detail, the potential vulnerability I noticed required a suggested edit to be present, so I had to use a second account. It's more of an edge case that the overwhelming majority of people will never run into, though.

Comment: @ErikA - technically that's not against the rules **as long as the first account doesn't interact with those questions**.

Comment: @jhpratt if you are talking about the hammer, it falls under "do something with one or more alternate accounts that you wouldn't be able to do with just your main account"

Comment: @ChrisF, it might not be against "the letter of the law" as it stands currently but it certainly feels like its well and truly poking a hole in the "spirit of the law" to do that =)

Comment: _"If you do something with one or more alternate accounts that you wouldn't be able to do with just your main account, then that's against the rules"_ - if your alt account earns more reputation that your main account, it gains more privileges. That's not against the rules, but I'm not sure how to rephrase that.

Comment: not that I am planning to do anything in that direction, but the "It boils down to: "something [...] you wouldn't be able to do with just your main account" does not include accepting answers, because that is something one can do with the main account only (I guess the awarded rep is different, if it isnt then actually I dont see what would be bad about doing it with two accounts)

Comment: @CodeCaster: What about *"You cannot use multiple accounts to do things that you would not be able to do with just one account."*? Does that sound better?

Comment: @Rob: While using an alternate account to ask bad questions isn't behavior we want to encourage, the problem there is _asking bad questions_, not using an alternate account to do it. In any case, if you use an account only for asking bad/unpopular questions, it's likely to soon get question banned. And at that point, using a second account to circumvent the ban _is_ explicitly forbidden. (*Also, insert appropriate disclaimers about how "unpopular" ≠ "bad"; none of that is directly relevant here, expect as a possible moral justification for posting questions that you know will be downvoted.*)

Comment: So you have to make sure to only vote on any post or comment with either your main account or your alternate account? And to make sure to keep the total votes you cast or number of reviews you perform in a day within the limits for a single account? That could be a bit painful to keep track of.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam: I believe the usual way to handle that is simply not to vote or review with your alternate account unless you absolutely have to. (The only reason I can think of why you _would_ have to is if you were, say, trying to reproduce a bug that only happens when voting/reviewing as a low-rep user. But in that case you'd presumably take extra care not to go over any limits or double-vote on anything.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen that's not actually true, at least to the letter as it is now, at least as far as the boiled down version goes (I'm unsure about the long ruleset). You _would_ have been able to ask all these bad questions from your main account, so creating multiple separate accounts to avoid the Q-ban on one doesn't actually allow you to do something you wouldn't be able to with just a single account.

Comment: How does one raise a sockpuppet-ry abuse issue?  Asking for a friend.

Comment: *"If you do something with one or more alternate accounts that you wouldn't be able to do with just your main account, then that's against the rules."* There is the rub; the only reason for an alternative account would be to be able to do something that you can't do with the main account.

Comment: @Eljay raise a custom flag against one of the users' posts. Give as much information as you can.

Comment: I don't know about SO, but on CG&CC I've often heard that people sometimes want to be able to suggest an edit or cast a close vote where they would end up actually executing the edit or hammering something closed, so one legitimate use of a non-bot alternate account could be to bypass the main account's privileges.

Comment: @unrelatedstring that's not a legitimate use of a second account. As mods we've been repeatedly told that we have these powers (instant close, delete etc) and should use them. If we have any doubts then don't act. The same applies to regular users.

Comment: As always, there's an XKCD for this https://xkcd.com/810/

Comment: @Cerbrus Why remove that added bullet, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Because it’s redundant.

Answer (score 17):

To cover the question itself directly (without retreading too much)

## Are we allowed to have multiple accounts?

In general, yes, as long as you're not doing [things in ChrisF's list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388985).

## What can we use those accounts for?

Mostly bots (automated programs) that need to use [Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) or the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) (anything [auth required in the list](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) needs an account). Probably the most famous bot out there is [Smoke Detector](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3735529/smokedetector) (Charcoal anti-spam project), but there are certainly others. If you have specific questions about running an acceptable bot, the [SOBotics team](https://sobotics.org/) can likely help you out in that department and they have [further suggestions on how to create bot accounts](https://blog.sobotics.org/2018/05/creating-a-bot-account).

## What are the rules governing multiple accounts?

While covered in detail in ChrisF's answer, the TL;DR is

1. Earn sockpuppet rep by normal user activity
2. Don't circumvent the rules

One he didn't mention is

- Make sure your bot's sockpuppet profile has some way to track you down if there's a problem. If a CM has to do it, they'll probably not be very happy with you...

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you read minds? I was thinking it might be helpful to post another answer. There's also a few points that have come up in the comments under the question - it would be good to clarify them somewhere. Maybe in Chris' answer

Comment: Why yes, yes I can! Actually, I thought we needed a TL;DR that tried to answer the questions raised (plus it's a good way to plug SoBotics). ChrisF has an excellent list of things to do and not to do, but it kinda missed that mark.

Comment: lol I have no issue with the bot work on the network being plugged. it's good for people to know what the main legit reason for sock accounts is. I have a sock account, I have brutalised with suspensions - both on main and in chat rooms, to test certain functionalities. I have it annotated on my account and the sock account that it's my account. Often it's a good idea to actually link it into your profile info. I don't do that with this account, as I don't really want it being in the public domain.