# How do I report about a person up voting using a second account

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Today I noticed the green tick was removed from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004437/python-scatter-plot-with-smooth-line/52005031#52005031).
Then I saw a green tick on an answer which is probably the questionnaire's other account.
In that, the currently accepted answer is copied from my answer.

I went through those profiles:

[Profile1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6449012/priyanka-baheti)

[Profile2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12052711/priyanka-baheti)

which seems to be the same person. Upvoting and accepting answer for the same account. It's ok if the accepted answer is correct, if not then this is a problem.

Where could I report or inform that this situation is happening?

Comment: Custom flag is usually the way to go. And it's ok to have to accounts. But they should not interact, and shouldn't be used to bypass anything on the platform (question limit, etc)

Comment: Try to specify this case in the custom flag, By the way if they can't get real reputation from other users on their own activity, I don't think they can do this stuff forever

Comment: If they are the same user... Did they comment saying thanks on their own answer then reply to themselves???

Comment: both give answer of thanks at the same time which same name of account,  and that question was asked at 2018. strange order of events

Comment: Related: [What are the rules governing multiple accounts (i.e. sockpuppets)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388984/1364007)

Comment: @Nihal it is indeed weird. But we don't have the tools mods do. Just flag it and let the experts handle it ^^

Comment: It is a bit easier to see that the user is plagiarizing posts from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57906244/17034).  The votes on it are more clearly fraudulent.

Comment: Please no witch hunting. Do not air drop downvoters on any target. One account is 2 day old it could be a fail in a smartphone account. Assume good faith.

Comment: @xdtTransform Except that Profile 2 answered three of Profile 1's questions, Profile 1 accepted all three answers, and the two profiles even exchanged comments on one of those answers (they've been deleted now but I took screenshots). There's no good-faith explanation for those actions. I'd say this is as slam-dunk as it gets.

Comment: @F1Krazy, I saw. Still if I saw it, mods will. No need to have link. It cost us nothing. I'm not Judging if it's real, malicious, cultural, or silly sock puppet. I'm saying we do not need the fuzz. The answers is custom flag mod. A simple mod message on both account and a link to merge account support should be enought

Comment: We do have mods to do exactly that. What does a witch hunt does? Honestly... except make us look like a pitchfork crowd...

Comment: @Patrice, one student once told me he can boost any account on SO. He just have to trigger the DW. Then chain post on meta "How to improve my question?" and "Why do you downvote". Then hit the "I have been serial downvoted" "Meta is harassing me" button.

Comment: @xdtTransform that's... disappointing :/

Comment: ..but not unexpected.  Really, does anyone assume good faith anymore?   A decade ago maybe, but surely, by now, all those 'nice' users have been beaten and mugged into acceptance of reality:(