# What are the concrete consequences of sockpuppets?

Tags: discussion, moderation, sock-puppets

I created two bots (alias [sockpuppets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet))). Both were taken down and I received a message from the moderators, saying that it is not fair and those accounts would be deleted.

Can this lead to further consequences like a deletion of my account?
And are there ways to use bots or extra accounts without having them taken down?

Comment: Starting from here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388984/what-are-the-rules-governing-multiple-accounts-i-e-sockpuppets you could learn everything you need to use sock puppets in a responsible way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> if moderators will pay closer attention to my actions now,

Moderators don't actively police "known felons."  They act in response to community flags raised against your posts.  It won't be an issue if you never get flagged again.

> how long the record of my bad behavior will be visible to moderators / stored on here

For as long as your main user account exists.

> whether this can lead to further consequences like a deletion of my account.

Only if the bad behavior continues.