# Should I flag one of the 2 answers of this question as plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers, plagiarism

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72757634/14732669) and 2 answers to the question in one of my review queues.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72757765/14732669
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72757800/14732669

Notice that they share a substantial portion of the same content, which I cannot locate as the given context in the question. I performed diff on the markdown of the 2 answers and it shows that they differ by some screenshots only. (If we don't count trivial wordings difference)
[image]

This leads me to the suspicion of plagiarism. However, I can only see the timestamp of the 2 answers as "yesterday", and I cannot confirm are they posted at similar time nor determine the order of posting.

So, my questions are:

1. Is this a plagiarism case?
2. If it is a plagiarism case, which answer should I flag as the plagiarizer if I cannot confirm the posting order?

Currently, I skipped the low-quality review tasks for both answers and did not flag any of the answers for moderator attention.

Comment: Odd indeed. I'd definitely flag for mod attention, though they were posted very close together, it's unlikely that they'd both get exactly the same formatting. That said, it may also be copied from the same external source (which I have not checked)

Comment: Quick note - UTC timestamps are available on hover. This is the "[original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72757765/11407695)" (2022-06-25 22:34:43Z) posted about 6 minutes before the other one (2022-06-25 22:41:42Z).

Comment: Also sorting by "Date created (oldest first)" as well as the [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72757634/timeline) can also show the order of posted answers. I'm also going with definitely plagiarism because the images use the exact same i.stack.imgur paths which is not possible unless it was copied directly from the source.

Comment: Thanks to both Henry and Oleg for the tips for determining the order first. Should I flag the second answer as plagiarizer, even if I am not 100% sure about that? It seems this is kind of leaving the burden of judgement to moderators.

Comment: Guess so, @ray - I haven't been able to find a common source, though. There is a possibility that the second user was actually trying to make an *edit* to the first user's post, though, that would explain WTF is going on there.

Comment: That's kind of what moderators are for. We expect them to use their judgement to handle things. Just be clear in your flag and outline the situation and what you need help with and they'll take care of the rest.

Comment: The short unique (and awkward) same-case phrases *"in MongoDB Site"* and *"After take your MongoDB URL"* is more than enough to deem it plagiarism. It doesn't have to be whole-sale copying.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

klutt describes the normal use case of a user being confused and copying a post instead of editing. Would have been my first guess too. The weird part here was the timing. As Qwertiy noted, the posts were made 7 minutes apart. That's not a lot of time for a plagiarist to make screenshots related to someone else's answer. That lead me to look at the user's rep graph and... he's suddenly quite popular! This is definitely mod flag material at this point.

A bit of digging on the mod end and it turns out the first answer was posted by his sock account. I left the real account's post (since it is an actual attempt at an answer and his sock is gone) and I've locked it for a day to limit Meta effect voting. **Please do not target the user for downvotes.** The situation has been dealt with.

If you ever see stuff like this, please do mod flag. Strange postings like this often lead to other issues.

Comment: What is a Sock account??

Comment: @Jacques A "sock" or "sockpuppet" account is another account controlled by the same person. We do allow you to have multiple accounts but [there are rules you must follow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388984/2370483). If you don't, a diamond moderator is likely to delete your other account(s)

Comment: Noticing the bold text for not targeting the user.... do meta users do this? The need for bold assumes yes but figured I'd ask

Comment: @JamesB It's more commonly called [Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350/2370483).

Answer (score 12):

I would not assume malicious intent here. It's quite likely that Thirosh Madhusha thought that the other answer would be better with the picture, but didn't know that they could or were allowed to edit the existing answer. And it's also likely that they copied the text from the same source.

I would either comment and ask about the reasoning or flag the mods explaining the situation.

Answer (score 6):

You can hover on "yesterday" and see full time in the tooltip:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72757765/14732669 - 2022-06-25 22:34:43Z
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72757800/14732669 - 2022-06-25 22:41:42Z